# Monotonic convergence of Newton's method for boundary value problems

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations

I’m interested in solving nonlinear elliptic boundary value problems of the type
$$
-a\Delta u + f\left(u\right) = 0,
\\
u\big\vert_\Gamma = u_0
$$
by Newton’s method when its convergence is global and monotonic.
Could you advice some references concerning this problem, containing proofs of global convergence?

Newton's method takes the form
$$
-a\,\Delta u + f\left(\widetilde u\right) + f'\left(\widetilde u\right)\left(u - \widetilde u\right) = 0
$$
where $\widetilde u$ is the previous approximation for the solution.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/20147/713

Comment: I've found an article by Schryer "Newton's method for convex nonlinear elliptic boundary value problem" but it concerns strong solutions. Are there articles concerning weak solutions?

Comment: @jokersobak You should edit the additional information you have found into the question if it belong there, or write it as an answer if it answers the question.